# Starting AppCompatActivity from Unity C# Script

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a hello world project. I have class called StartActivity class which extends from AppCompatActivity. I have created an .aar lib and placed it under unity plugins folder. The idea is to launch the activity from unity android app so I am starting the activity from unity. When I try to start my activity from unity it throws an error saying the class StartActivity could not be found. When I extend the same class from Activity or UnityPlayerActivity class it works. But I need AppCompatActivity class features so cannot move to other classes.
This my manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sitagy.helloworld">
 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 
        <activity android:name="com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartUpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name = "com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name = "com.example.sitagy.helloworld.MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
 
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

The following is my java class

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    private String TAG = "Plug.StartActivity";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("SY : on create start neew activity");
 
    }
    public static void Call(Activity activity)
    {
        // Creating an intent with the current activity and the activity we wish to start
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, StartActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    public static void CallStatic()
    {
        System.out.println("CallStatic")
    }
```

The following is my c# code

```
   void Start()
    {
   
        var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartActivity");
        jc.CallStatic("Call", jo);
 
}
```

If I extend the StartActivity to just regular activity it works. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. I have the AppCompat libs under plugins folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx8in.png)

This is the error for adb log

--------- beginning of crash
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.captivereality.javaunityplugin, PID: 26868
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/sitagy/helloworld/StartActivity;
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.java:17)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartActivity
08-01 17:43:04.766 26868 26868 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 16 more
08-01 17:43:04.769   910 26893 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
08-01 17:43:04.770   910  2871 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.captivereality.javaunityplugin/com.example.sitagy.helloworld.StartUpActivity

Any help would be great!!
Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. So we need to add every supported library mentioned under External Libraries in Android Studio to Unity Plugin/Android folder.